# I need help to see who would of won this hand

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

If the board had A,A,3,6,6

In my hand I had a 9,3.
My oppents hand had a Q,5 
Who wins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my knowledge of poker hands, this looks like your opponent has the best hand with the best possible 5 cards being A,A,6,6,Q. This translates to aces and sixes with a Queen kicker.

This beats your best possible hand of A,A,6,6,9

Comment: Thanks I thought they were lying to me cause I had a pair on the board

Comment: @Helen Yes I had that same confusion, I haven't played in a while and I was under the false impression that a pair made up of a card in your hand is better than on the flop and river and so on. Its calculated by the best possible hand between all cards in play.